# Server Error in Android Volley Request Status Code 500

Tags: python, android, heroku, android-volley, flask-restful

I have deployed an Flask API in Heroku. Trying to hit the Flask API through Android Volley POST request. But the log file shows NetworkUtility.shouldRetryException: Unexpected response code 500.
I have Tested on Postman.it works perfect.I don't know what is the problem, stuck here for 2 days.
My URL for the Heroku app is correct.
In my Heroku app log file : also shows an error "TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object".
Here is my MainActivity.java :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText question;
    Button btn;
    TextView textView;
    Button reset;
    String url = "https://krishokbot.herokuapp.com/chatbot";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        question = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.question);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        reset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reset);

       btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
               StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                   @Override
                   public void onResponse(String response) {
                       try {
                           JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                           String data = jsonObject.getString("response");
                           textView.setText(data);

                       } catch (JSONException e) {
                           e.printStackTrace();
                       }
                   }
               }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                       NetworkResponse networkResponse = error.networkResponse;
                       if (networkResponse != null) {
                           Log.e("Volley", "Error. HTTP Status Code:" + networkResponse.statusCode);
                       }

                       if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                           Log.e("Volley", "TimeoutError");
                       } else if (error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                           Log.e("Volley", "NoConnectionError");
                       } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                           Log.e("Volley", "AuthFailureError");
                       } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                           Log.e("Volley", "ServerError");
                       } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                           Log.e("Volley", "NetworkError");
                       } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                           Log.e("Volley", "ParseError");
                       }
                       Log.d("Maps:", " Error: " + error.getMessage());

                   }
               }) {
                   @Override
                   protected Map<String,String> getParams() {
                       Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                       params.put("question", question.getText().toString());
                       return params;
                   }
               };

               RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
               queue.add(stringRequest);
           }


       });


    }

}

from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify, request
import chatbot_response

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "hello_world"
ar
@app.route('/chatbot', methods=['POST'])
def chatbotResponse():
    question = request.args.get('question')
    response = chatbot_response.chatbot_response(question)
    return jsonify({"response": str(response)})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Heroku log Image link : [https://ibb.co/jRtBfN4]

Comment: [HTTP 500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) is a generic server-side error message. On its own it doesn't tell us anything useful. Any time you see this your first step should be to check your error logs for more detail. On Heroku, do that by running [`heroku logs`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-logs).

Comment: (a) [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code. (b) If you _are_ going to post screenshots (only of things that aren't text), do it on the official image host.

Comment: Putting those two comments together: Please [edit] your post and replace your ibb.co link with the logs _as a code block_.